# POST and GET image using SAILJS does not work (error: [object, Object]) While uploading Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

This is my code which is referred to sails documentation I want to upload an image for file controller action and get it upload and store it through user controller action upload and get. It is not working its show an

```
error: [object, Object].
```

file controller action
for uploading image

// myApp/api/controllers/FileController.js

```
module.exports = {

  index: function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'content-type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.end(
      //'<form action="http://localhost:1337/file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
      '<form action="http://localhost:1337/user/avatar" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
      '<input type="text" name="title"><br>' +
      '<input type="file" name="avatar" multiple="multiple"><br>' +
      '<input type="submit" value="Upload">' +
      '</form>'
    )
  },
  /**
   * User Controller action
   * for upload andget image
   * Upload avatar for currently logged-in user
   *
   * (POST /user/avatar)
   */
  uploadAvatar: function (req, res) {
    console.log('avatar', req.method);
    console.log(req.session.me);
    req.file('avatar').upload({
      // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
      maxBytes: 10000000
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) {
        return res.negotiate(err);
      }
      console.log(uploadedFiles);

      // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
      if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
        return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
      }


      // Save the "fd" and the url where the avatar for a user can be accessed
      User.update(req.session.me, {

          // Generate a unique URL where the avatar can be downloaded.
          avatarUrl: require('util').format('%s/user/avatar/%s', sails.getBaseUrl(), req.session.me),

          // Grab the first file and use it's fd (file descriptor)
          avatarFd: uploadedFiles[0].fd
        })
        .exec(function (err) {
          if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
          return res.ok();
        });
    });
  },


  /**
   * Download avatar of the user with the specified id
   *
   * (GET /user/avatar/:id)
   */
  avatar: function (req, res) {

    console.log('avatar', req.method);
    console.log(req.session.me);
    req.validate({
      //id: 'string'
      id: '57053900e15832cc51b84c47'
    });

    User.findOne(req.param('id')).exec(function (err, user) {


      if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
      if (!user) return res.notFound();

      // User has no avatar image uploaded.
      // (should have never have hit this endpoint and used the default image)
      if (!user.avatarFd) {
        return res.notFound();
      }

      var SkipperDisk = require('skipper-disk');
      var fileAdapter = SkipperDisk(/* optional opts */);

      // Stream the file down
      fileAdapter.read(user.avatarFd)
        .on('error', function (err) {
          return res.serverError(err);
        }).pipe(res);
    });
  }
};
```

[image: File controller action]
[image: Error msg]
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: how many line occur error?  and show detail error message.

Comment: 3 to 4 line of error i have posted the error image  also. Thanks

Comment: 3 to 4 line of error i have just posted error image.

Comment: check your err message of below line.

if(err) { 
  console.log(err); // check this.
  res.negotiate(err);
}

and check networks tab of chrome developer tools.